# LVM on images very slow

Tags: lvm

After creating an lvm

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=1.img bs=1M count=16384
dd if=/dev/zero of=2.img bs=1M count=16384
losetup /dev/loop1 1.img
losetup /dev/loop2 2.img
pvcreate /dev/loop1
pvcreate /dev/loop2
vgcreate LVM1 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2
vgchange -an LVM1
```

I allocate 10G volume and format it

```
lvcreate -L10240 -n lv_34179984_0 LVM1
mkfs.xfs /dev/LVM1/lv_34179984_0
mount -t xfs /dev/LVM1/lv_34179984_0 /home/test/image
```

When I try to copy a 8G file to /home/test/image it blocks after 215M copied, iostat gives me

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.00   29.82    0.00   70.18

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda3              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     1.00    0.00   0.00 100.20
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you able to perform other operations on the LVM when your copy stalls?  Also what state is the `cp` process in? (is it waiting on a read, or a write?)

Comment: What if you use ext4 instead of xfs?

Comment: whole lvm hangs, cannot execute even ls

Comment: hangs on writing

Answer (score 4):

You solve this by not creating a filesystem on top of volume group on top of files that are already in a filesystem (possibly in a volume group) on a disk.  To use an Inception reference, you've gone too deep my friend.

Every time you try to do something on `/home/test/image` your system has to go through the following steps:

- Filesystem operation on `/home/test/image`

  - Volume Group operation
  - Virtual disk (loop device) operation on `loop1`

    - Filesystem operation on `1.img`

      - Disk operation on wherever `1.img` lives
  - Virtual disk (loop device) operation on `loop2`

    - Filesystem operation on `2.img`

      - Disk operation on wherever `2.img` lives

This still leaves out a bunch of intermediate steps that happen in the kernel whenever you initiate disk I/O (physical disk or loop device).  Simply put, you're asking your system to do so much work the performance will be lousy.

You can marginally improve the performance by putting `1.img` and `2.img` on separate physical disks, but that is unlikely to give a substantial benefit.  Your only real option for decent performance is to create the volume group on *physical disks*.

Comment: ok, performance is predictably bad, but why copy process blocks after 215M, really blocks (ps gives DNl), no bytes were written after this mark to the destination, maybe some buffers become full

Comment: This is not asking too much, and works just fine ( even performance wise ) when I do it on an Ubuntu Lucid system.  It seems that the OP is simply running a buggy kernel.